# Is it true that $\oplus_G H \cong \mathbb{Z}[G] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} H$ as $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ module?

Tags: group-theory, modules, abelian-groups

Let $H$ be an abelian group and $G$ be any group. Then is it true that 
$ \oplus_{G} H $ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[G] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} H$ as $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ module. I am asking it following the question 
[Homology of $X_{\infty}$ space for a given Seifert surface of an oriented link $L$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3340057/homology-of-x-infty-space-for-a-given-seifert-surface-of-an-oriented-link) asked me. In that question 
$H_i(Y' \cap Y''; \mathbb{Z})= \mathbb{Z}[t^{-1},t] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} H_i(F;Z)$ for $i=0,1$. But basic calculations suggest that $H_i(Y' \cap Y''; \mathbb{Z})= \oplus_{\langle t \rangle} H_i(F;\mathbb{Z})$, where $\langle t\rangle$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$. Thus I am thinking that $\oplus_G H \cong \mathbb{Z}[G] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} H$ as $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ module may be true, but I am not able to define map or produce a counterexample.

Can anyone help me in resolving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\oplus_G H$ as ${\Bbb Z}[G]$-module:

$g' \cdot h_g  = h_{g'g}$

and ${\Bbb Z}[G]\otimes_{\Bbb Z} H$ as ${\Bbb Z}[G]$-module:

$g'(g\otimes h) = (g'g)\otimes h$.

Then the morphism is given by

$h_g \mapsto g\otimes h$

with $g'\cdot h_g = h_{g'g}\mapsto (g'g)\otimes h = g'(g\otimes h)$.